# Нормальна ли авторизация в React приложении через сессии php (REST API)

Tags: php, reactjs, http, auth, axios

Я писал PHP приложения где авторизация через сессии нормальна для меня, я понимаю что сессия хранится в браузере, теперь я пишу React приложения и тут сессия хранится в браузере от имени домена api, мне это кажется непривычным и неправильным, что можете сказать на эту тему?

Может есть более безопасная и правильная авторизация для React приложений, например HTTP авторизация, никогда её не пользовался но представляю что это.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я пишу бэкенд на Python-Django + React, но патерны одинаковые так что, можешь попробовать JWT, идеально работают с React и их просто использовать . Отправляешь POST запрос с username и password. В ответ получаешь 2 токена access и refresh (которые могут генерироваться на секретном ключе для безопасности). Access токен нужно будет вставлять в заголовки чтобы подтверждать юзера а Refresh сохранить в LocalStorage с его помощью можно получить access токен. У всех токенов можно установить срок жизни.

Comment: Можно пригласить тебя сюда https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1121246/Подробный-разбор-авторизации-пользователя-через-jwt-api-php-react )